# Getting an error when try to do peering via Azure Devops Service Connection

Tags: azure, devops, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to create a peering between two virtual networks that reside in two different tenant using azure devops release pipelines.
Here's the error I get from the failed deployment:

LinkedAuthorizationFailed: The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/peer/action' on scope '/subscriptions//resourcegroups/RG-VNet-A/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vNet01/virtualNetworkPeerings/Tenant-A-to-Tenant-B', however the current tenant '***' is not authorized to access linked subscription 'tenant A subcription ID'.

Comment: Is the multi-tenant option enabled for the Service Principal in use ? If so, does it have proper permissions on both scopes ?

Answer (score 0):

> LinkedAuthorizationFailed: The client has permission to perform action
> 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/peer/action' on scope
> '/subscriptions//resourcegroups/RG-VNet-A/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vNet01/virtualNetworkPeerings/Tenant-A-to-Tenant-B',
> however the current tenant '***' is not authorized to access linked
> subscription 'tenant A subcription ID'.

The service connection in your DevOps project only have access to the virtual network in one tenant. It does not have access to the virtual network in the other tenant.

You can assign **Network Contributor** role to that virtual network and you would be able to peer the two virtual networks using Azure DevOps pipelines